# How to normalize an array of objects in the flattest way for the Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, normalizr

> Beware! The question may be confusing and not relevant because my
>   assumptions about the cause of the bug were wrong, the problem was in
>   reducer, not in a way I represented a data.
>
> So, the correct answer for the question is *jpdelatorre*’s one, but
>   *Joao*’s is about the bug itself.

Let’s say I have JSON response from server which is an array of nested objects. How to flatten it out making store handling as easy as possible? I’ve tried to use a normalizr tool like this:

```
const imageSchema = new Schema('image', { idAttribute: 'id' });
const tooltipSchema = new Schema('tooltips', { idAttribute: 'id' });
imageSchema.define({
    tooltips: arrayOf(tooltipSchema),
});
const initData = data.map(item => normalize(item, imageSchema));
```

But I believe I’m doing it wrong because it doesn’t help much. The store is still too complex and therefore I need to use some recursive stuff in reducer to update the state.

Moreover, a deeply nested state makes working with react-redux `connect()` very hard too, because [it does only a shallow comparison](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/282).

The shape of the response is like:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Partridge",
    "tooltips": [
      {
        "id": 10,
        "x": 0.56,
        "y": 0.59,
        "content": "Jacky"
      },
      {
        "id": 11,
        "x": 0.08,
        "y": 0.8,
        "content": "Sarah"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "The Great Seal of South Australia",
    "tooltips": [
      {
        "id": 20,
        "x": 0.77,
        "y": 0.74,
        "content": "A sheaf of wheat"
      },
      {
        "id": 21,
        "x": 0.16,
        "y": 0.2,
        "content": "A sheep"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: I know there’s a lot of similar q’s but them haven’t help me :-(

Comment: Where is the difficulty in having deeply-nested objects in your state? Is it in updating the state? Can you provide examples?

Comment: It making hard to apply updates in reducers and causes some troubles for `connect()`

Comment: Deeply-nested objects shouldn't cause difficulty for `connect()`, I've had some doozies with no problems. Are you trying to update the entire object in the reducer? Or just trying to update, say, the tooltips array?

Comment: Here's a simplified sample of the reducer's logic: https://jsbin.com/yenoyep/edit?js

Comment: > Are you trying to update the entire object in the reducer? Yep, is this stupid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this with [normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr)

```
const imgSchema = new Schema('image', { idAttribute: 'id'});
const tooltipSchema = new Schema('tooltip');
imgSchema.define({
   tooltips: arrayOf(tooltipSchema)
});

const normalizedData = normalize(data, arrayOf(imgSchema));
console.log(normalizedData);
```

This will give you an output of

```
{
   entities: {
      image: {
         1: {
            id: 1,
            title: 'Partride',
            tooltips: [10, 11]
         },
         2: {
            id: 2,
            title: 'The Great Seal...',
            tooltips: [20, 21]
         }
      },
      tooltips: {
          10: {
              id: 10,
              content: 'Jacky',
              x: 0.56,
              y: 0.59
          },
          ...
      }
   },
   result: [1, 2]
}
```

You can then save it to your redux store.

Your question is **How to normalize an array of objects in the flattest way for the Redux?**. I believe this is how to do it.

Comment: Nowadays there's a `schema.Array` method that does exactly what you wrote.
[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-forked-nluj3?file=/src/index.ts)

Answer (score 5):

Based on your sample [here](https://jsbin.com/yenoyep/edit?js), It seems like you're trying to modify the state (hence the reason you're having trouble because of redux's shallow comparison). State should be regarded as immutable and everything returned in your reducers should be completely new objects. `Object.assign` modifies the first argument.

Try replacing `return Object.assign(state, { data: newEntities })`

with `return Object.assign({}, state, { data: newEntities })`

If you stick with this, flat data structure is not needed.

Comment: Oh. My. Gosh. You're absolutely right, man, thanks so much! Glad you help me to find that stupid bug.